# Magento Custom admin controller permissions

Tags: magento, acl

I have created this custom backend route :

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <mycustombackendroute>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Custom_Module_Adminhtml</module>
                <frontName>mycustombackendroute</frontName>
            </args>
        </mycustombackendroute>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

When I am an administrator, I can access this route just fine. However with a restricted administor user, I am unable to create an ACL allowing me to give the rights to use this controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution. After creating my ACL :

```
<adminhtml>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <mymodule>
                        <title>Module ACL title</title>
                        <children>
                            <myaction>
                                <title>ACL title</title>
                            </myaction>
                        </children>
                    </mymodule>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</adminhtml>
```

I have added the following code in my controller :

```
public function _isAllowed()
{
    return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('mymodule/myaction');
}
```

Comment: This is the right way to approach it, but I found my answer in this question: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73646/access-denied-errors-after-installing-supee-6285

Comment: for <mymodule> title also required. If you will not add it - it will be hidden in roles tree.